# FreePascal: Identifier not found "MEMW"

Tags: freepascal

I am migrating a Turbo Pascal application into Free Pascal 32 bit for Windows 7 operating system. Whenever I compiled unit file in Free Pascal, the compiler shows error message:

```
Identifier not found `MEMW`.
```

Can anybody help me on this? My code is shown below, is there any option to implement the same thing?

```
PROCEDURE window_object.appear; 

VAR 
   width_offset, 
   height_offset    : BYTE; 
   current_location : location_pointer; 

BEGIN 
     current_location:=first_location; 
     FOR height_offset:=y TO (y+y_offset-1) DO 
     BEGIN 
          FOR width_offset:=x TO (x+x_offset-1) DO 
          BEGIN 
               **MEMW[$B800:(width_offset-1)*2 
                         +(height_offset-1)*160]:=current_location^.code;**
               current_location:=current_location^.next; 
          END; 
     END; 
     current_location^.next:=NIL; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Access to the DOS screen at $B800 is **only possible in DOS versions.**

DOS versions are only supported in dosboxes of Win98, so not supported under Windows NT variants like NT4/W2k/XP/w2003,vista,w2008,w7,w8(.1)

In general, code relying on DOS direct screen access schould be rewritten to use the **video unit**.

The Video unit is platform independent, and maintains a virtual screen buffer. The  VideoBuf variable allows direct access to it. Procedural variables can be used to minimize the needed modifications:

Recently I made a simple unit for the TP dialedit program (which is a Turbo Vision application).

For this to work, the main program needs

1. to call video.initvideo on startup
2. video.donevideo on shutdown.
3. Non Turbo Vision programs need to also call updatescreen(false) to update the screen (e.g. as the last line in your function)

The unit:

```
unit videord;
// emulates three param screen[] array for dialedit.
// can't be in dialedit since procedural properties aren't allowed in $mode tp
interface

uses Video;


function videoreadchar(x,y,z:integer):char;

// Coordinates are 1 based, z=0 gets the character, z=1 gets the attribute.    
property screen[x,y,z:integer]:char read videoreadchar;


implementation
function videoreadchar(x,y,z:integer):char;

Var
  P: Integer;

begin
  P:=((X-1)+(Y-1)*ScreenWidth);
  videoreadchar:=pchar(@VideoBuf^[P])[z];
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks, I used same (Video Unit) but throwing runtime error "Program Received Signal SIGSEGV Segmentation fault".